# Responsive margin resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I want to have my elements resize their margins equally so that they fill the page. I tried turning the page width into a value using jquery but that didn't work.

```
var margen = $(window).width()
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FixedMenu *').animate({
        'margin-left': 'margen/6'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/2PGZS/40/

Comment: i dont know why you calculate margen/6 but see this http://jsfiddle.net/2PGZS/41/ maybe it will help you

Comment: Did exactly the same, you got there before me ^

Comment: Right now you're passing a string, as it's quoted, and anything that is quoted is a string. Just remove the quotes around `'margen/6'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make little update to your jsFiddle, you can see it here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PGZS/43/)

What i change is this:

1.

You found width of screen:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
```

2.

You found total width of child elements of your fixed menu

```
var widthOfChilds = 0;
$('#FixedMenu > *').each(function() {
    widthOfChilds += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
```

3.

You take off total width of child elements from screen size and you will get "free"width around child elements.
There are six of them, but you need space after last one from right, so you divide "free"width by number of childs + 1

```
var newmargin = (screenWidth - widthOfChilds)/7;
$('#FixedMenu *').animate({
    'margin-left': newmargin
});
```

I hope it helped! :)

Comment: You are VERY intelligent! I couldn't have thought of _that_!